# Show div at node position

Tags: cytoscape.js

I try to show a div at the node position when the node is clicked, but it does not seem to work; I found the properties `position` and `renderedPosition` of the event object, I believed that I could use them to set the position properties of the div, but with no success. What am I doing wrong ?

here the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m8wzcjqn/1/

Comment: At first, div should have absolute position

Comment: I put absolute to the div to move, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b8js4ev5/ ; but it does not move when clicking the node

Comment: The x,y coordinates coming from the tap event are coordinates relative to the canvas. You need to put your div according to global coordinates.